# What is the Surah that ends with the name of that Surah?

Tags: quran

I need this for a question my teacher asked me, I can't find any info.

Comment: Note that some surahs have multiple names.  So for example the 111'st Surah is also a valid answer to this question since one of its names is Surah Massad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't that very simple? it is last Surah Al-Nas https://quran.com/114

There is also another sura, which have last word same as it name, it is sura Al-Maa'oon. https://quran.com/107

[image]

[image]